# How many Evolution Points do you need to become fully evolved in Prototype 1

Tags: prototype

As in the title, whats the magic number of Evolution Points needed to Fully Evolve Alex Mercer?

On the side, do you have to complete any of the challenge missions to get enough EPs to fully evolve? (Ignoring the fact that you can get EP's from killing infected and military)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my math is correct you will need **17 923 600 EP**

[Here](http://prototype.wikia.com/wiki/Upgrades) is full list of "skill" costs.

Not sure but I think you will need to "grind" some points to get all upgrades,on average you can get over 150 000 points per mission + additional bonuses,with 10 episodes in the game I believe you will still be short some EPs.